# Acts like an array of structs without declaring array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, struct, output

I started to write this code for fun and I was surprised that it compiled and worked. (I'm using Dev C++ to compile.) I wanted to create an array of structs but before I created the array, It stored and read the values like it was already an array. Why Is this, and how may I still create an array of structs so I can keep track of the total size of the array?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Shape
{
 public:
 int x,y,z;
};

struct Triangle: public Shape
{
 public:
 int tNum;
};

struct Rectangle: public Shape
{
 public:
 int rNum;
 float differentNum;
};

struct Circle: public Shape
{
 public:
 int cNum;
}; 

int main(void)
{ int i;
 Triangle tri;
 Rectangle rec; 
 Circle cir; 
 Shape *arr[3]={&tri, &rec, &cir};

 for(i=1;i<5;i++){ arr[1][i].x=i*2; cout<<"set  tri["<<i<<"] "<<i*2<<endl;} cout<<endl; 
 for(i=1;i<5;i++){ arr[2][i].x=i*9; cout<<"set  rec["<<i<<"] "<<i*9<<endl;} cout<<"-----------------"<<endl;

 for(i=1;i<5;i++){ cout<<"read tri["<<i<<"] "<<arr[1][i].x<<endl;} cout<<endl;
 for(i=1;i<5;i++){ cout<<"read rec["<<i<<"] "<<arr[2][i].x<<endl;}

 system("pause");
 return(0);
}

/*output   
set  tri[1] 2   
set  tri[2] 4  
set  tri[3] 6  
set  tri[4] 8  

set  rec[1] 9  
set  rec[2] 18  
set  rec[3] 27  
set  rec[4] 36  
-----------------`  
read tri[1] 2  
read tri[2] 4  
read tri[3] 6  
read tri[4] 8

read rec[1] 9  
read rec[2] 18  
read rec[3] 27  
read rec[4] 36*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of 3 `Shape*` variables, each pointing to a valid `Shape` instance in the stack:

- `arr[0]` is pointing to the `tri` instance, so `arr[0][0]` is the `tri` instance.
- `arr[1]` is pointing to the `rec` instance, so `arr[1][0]` is the `rec` instance.
- `arr[2]` is pointing to the `cir` instance, so `arr[2][0]` is the `cir` instance.

Any other use of `arr` is basically illegal (even though it might work).

Although it is not recommended, the fact that the `rec` instance and the `cir` instance appear in the stack immediately after the `tri` instance, allows you to use `arr` in a few other ways and "stay alive":

- `arr[0][1]` is the `rec` instance, which appears in the stack after the `tri` instance.
- `arr[0][2]` is the `cir` instance, which appears in the stack after the `rec` instance.
- `arr[1][1]` is the `cir` instance, which appears in the stack after the `rec` instance.

As pointed out in one of the comments below, it really depends on the implementation of the stack.

Any other (different) attempt to access memory through `arr` is a potential memory access violation.

**Here is how you should probably do it:**

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
protected:
    Shape() {}
    virtual ~Shape() {}
    string type;
    int x,y,z;
public:
    string GetType() const {return type;}
    void SetX(int val) {x = val;}
    void SetY(int val) {y = val;}
    void SetZ(int val) {z = val;}
};

class Triangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Triangle():type("Triangle") {}
    void SetNum(int val) {tNum = val;}
private:
    int tNum;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle():type("Rectangle") {}
    void SetNum(int val) {rNum = val;}
    void SetDifferentNum(float val) {differentNum = val;}
private:
    int   rNum;
    float differentNum;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle():type("Circle") {}
    void SetNum(int val) {cNum = val;}
private:
    int cNum;
};

...

Triangle  tri;
Rectangle rec;
Circle    cir;
Shape*    arr[3] = {&tri, &rec, &cir};
int       size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    arr[i]->SetX(i*2);
    cout << "set " << arr[i]->GetType() << "[" << i << "] = " << i*2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Results depend on if the stack grows up or down.

Comment: @brian beuning, thanks for pointing that out. In any case, I did emphasize "at the middle" of the answer that 'Any other use of `arr` is basically illegal (even though it might work)'.

Comment: oh ok thank you. Is there a way for me to create an array of pointers of rec and still use this method where I call arr?

Comment: @user3341184: added a suggestion of how you should probably do it.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. This looks interesting. I like it but it wont compile for me. "class `Triangle' does not have any field named `type'" Does this mean i need c++11 or something else to make it compile? It doesn't seem to like "type".

Comment: @user3341184: You probably need to `#include <string>` and declare `using namespace std` at the beginning of your code (I assumed that you had already done that); see updated answer above...

Answer (score 0):

You have some seriously **undefined behavior** going on here; your code is not doing what you may think it's doing.  for example, `arr[2]` is a pointer to `cir`, but `arr[2][1]` and `arr[2][2]` are pointers to uninitialized blocks of memory.  From your definition

```
Shape *arr[3]={&tri, &rec, &cir};
```

you can safely access `arr[0]` (a pointer to `tri`), `arr[1]` (a pointer to `rec`) and `arr[2]` (a pointer to `cir`), but that's all.